# Mapping Oracle 11g virtual columns in Hibernate

Tags: oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

A number of questions in this regard:-

a. Is there a specific hibernate `type` to be used for oracle 11g virtual columns or the native ones would do?

b. If types e.g., `string`, `long` are to be used (and they do work fine when used in hql queries) then how to fetch the properties mapped onto virtual columns using Criteria API?

c. Currently, criteria query returns such properties as empty although they do have values in them. As an alternative I have used the `formula` element by calling the function used to derive the virtual column and that returns the result set with actual values. But then, having a virtual column in table is of no use as the processing overhead again shifts to hibernate/ application code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when calling the sproc the processing is done in oracle not client. it is basicly the same as fetching the virtual columns no?

Comment: Yes, it is I think. But even in oracle the overhead is there for explicitly calling a pl/sql function. A virtual column gives the benefit by getting rid of this overhead. One more thing, the criteria queries use joining. It is perhaps somewhere in that joining that the virtual columns are fetch as empty. Is there a way to control the behaviour of joins in criteria queries?

Comment: try capture the sql generated by nhibernate (internal logger/log4net) and run it directly, if it returns the correct results then problem is on NH mapping side else it is the database returning empty values

Comment: not for .NET - I work with oracle 11g database and java. And yes, I tried with the sql generated by criteria query. It returns empty values for the virtual columns. Its something to do with the joins in criteria. even if there are no parameters passed to the criteria queries, i.e., in case of default select, the result is the same empty values. But a simple hql query DOES return values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the virtual columns, nothing that Hibernate can do about it since it just generates sql.

the easiest way would be to use formula properties instead of virtual columns.
if virtual columns are precomputed then you could simulate them with normal columns and triggers.